# Is Azure Functions running in Consumption mode appropriate for massively varying, yet time critical Load?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I’m about to start work on an API that will literally go from 0 RPS to a couple hundred thousand **HTTP** RPS at the same time and run at that rate for ~2 mins.  All processing of those 30 million requests must finish by the end of that 2 min period.  This would happen 7 times a *WEEK.*

Going serverless with Azure Functions in Consumption Plan Hosting Mode sounds appealing.  [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) describes that a scale controller exists to coordinate app instances, but doesn't really discuss what I can expect from it for HTTP triggers. I can’t find any info that says the scale controller will be able to respond in the time frame I'd need.

The best info I could find was [this info](http://anthonychu.ca/post/scaling-azure-functions-http/) saying it took nearly 8 mins to scale up for his tests.

Is this a bad use case for Azure Functions in consumption mode?

Obviously, spinning up a testing harness that is capable of issuing 30 million requests within 2 minutes is an undertaking of its own, and an expensive one.  I'd like to learn from others who have already done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experience, this scenario is not properly covered by Consumption Plan. They can scale up to many instances, but not very rapidly. 2 minutes is way too fast to rely on.

I was mostly working with queues, not HTTP, but I got delays up to 40 minutes caused by low pace of scaling up.

If you can predict which 2 minutes are going to be heavy-loaded, your best bet could be to provision the capacity with a script (or another Function).

Comment: you can also use autoscale rules to configure your plan to scale up to a specified number of instances based on a schedule. For more info see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling

Comment: @PaulBatum You cannot configure autoscale for the Consumption Plan, which was at the heart of my question.  I was hoping someone could chime in and explain how HTTP triggered functions would scale... meaning how quickly, to what limits, and by what measures.  I understand I can pick an App Service Plan as the Hosting Plan and take control of the scale up/down.  However, my API will be used for about 14 minutes a WEEK... so I was hoping the Consumption plan would drop to $0 for majority of the other 10,066 minutes in the week.

Comment: My comments about auto scale were in regards to Mikhail's recommendation for using an app service plan. He is corrrct that the consumption plan will not perform adequately for this scenario (as of august 2017). Both in terms of scaling to 200K+ RPS and how quickly the scale out is required.