# What are the expected performance characteristics of an Azure Function App in Consumption mode?

Tags: performance, azure, performance-testing, azure-functions

What are the expected performance characteristics of an Azure Function App in Consumption mode?

I was going to ask *... How can you carry out realistic testing of an Azure Function App?*

A person in the team knocked together a Perl script that forked off and called our Function App to very crudely simulate the sort of load we're hoping to cope with, e.g. starting with say 150,000 users, calling 10 time a second

The script was running on a very beefy VM running over in Google

Things started Ok with lower numbers, but very quickly we started getting timeouts

We must be doing something "wrong", as I sort of assume that Function App's can cope with this sort of load ... **but what?**

... and can they cope with this load in Consumption Plan mode?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558305/is-azure-functions-running-in-consumption-mode-appropriate-for-massively-varying/45561640#45561640)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into ARR-Affinity cookies and see if it is causing scaling problems.

When I was performing some load testing with my function I noticed all the traffic was only going to one instance, and it turned out to be a problem with AAR-Affinity cookies. The load client was being directed back to the same function instance for every request, so it was not scaling out to meet the demand.

You can disable this behavior to see if you get better scaling behavior.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/

or adding this response header.

Headers.Add("Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");